# Team Foundation Server GAC

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, gac, tfs-2015

I am in the process of adding a standalone solution so source control (Team Foundation Server 2015).
The solution contains several SSRS reports (rdlc) each of which consume a strongly signed assembly (used for generating barcodes).
I have added the strongly signed **barcode.dll** to the solution in a **Binaries** folder and ensured that is also added to source control.
The problem I am having is that when building the solution TFS is returning the error

```
Error rsErrorLoadingCodeModule: Error while loading code module...
```

I believe the reason for this is that when compiling the SSRS reports, each report looks to the local GAC for the strongly named assembly.

Does anybody know how I could add a step/powershell script that would allow me to register the **\Binaries\Barcode.dll** assembly in the GAC prior to building the solution?

Any help, thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way: copy your **\Binaries\Barcode.dll** to the build agent. And manually register this dll in the GAC.

> To install a strong-named assembly into the global assembly cache
> using the Global Assembly Cache tool (Gacutil.exe)
>
> •At the command prompt, type the following command:
>
> gacutil –I
>
> Source (MSDN):  [How to: Install an Assembly into the Global Assembly Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your project is not referencing the DLL from it's on-disk location, but is instead referencing it without a location (and thus using the GAC).  You need to remove the reference from the project, then re-add it from the location on disk.  A better choice, however, might be to add the file to a Nuget package (if one does not already exist) and then add it to a local NuGet repository, then add that to your packages.conf.  Make sure the reference has the "Copy Local" option set to True.

Another option is to use the new Package Management extension to TFS that Microsoft has recently released.